# Why are all dropdown lists updating to the same selected value?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, drop-down-menu

I have a web form that I use as an input form.  It has five dropdown lists.  When the page initializes, each dropdown list has the same set of values.  The default selected value is "select" (selected text is "Select").  If I load the page with no URL parameter, it is a blank input form.  If I load the page with the URL parameter "?ID=00001" then it loads the data from record 00001.

Here is the problem.  When I load the data from a record (in this case, "00001"), all of the dropdown lists update with the same selected value.  I have tried this umpteen different ways and keep getting the same result and cannot figure out why.  I have never had a problem like this before.

Here is the latest version of the code that I have attempted, below.  The XML file that the data is pulled from may have one to five "media" child nodes in the "social" node.  The "ID" attribute from the first "media" child node should be used to select a value from the first dropdown list (ddlSocial1).  The "ID" attribute from the second "media" child node should be used to select a value from the second dropdown list (ddlSocial2), and so on.  What actually happens is that, regardless of how many "media" child nodes are in the "social" node, ALL FIVE of the dropdown lists have selected values equal to the "ID" attribute of the last "media" child node.  So, if there are four "media" child nodes, all five dropdown lists have the selected value of the "ID" attribute of the fourth "media" child node.  All of the code below is contained within an "if (Page.IsPostBack == false)" conditional.

```
int s = 1;
XmlNodeList allSocials = getPublisherData.SelectNodes("publisher/social/media");
foreach (XmlNode eachSocial in allSocials)
{
    if (s == 1) { ddlSocial1.SelectedValue = eachSocial.Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString(); txtSocial1.Text = eachSocial.InnerText; } else { ddlSocial1.SelectedValue = "select"; }
    if (s == 2) { ddlSocial2.SelectedValue = eachSocial.Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString(); txtSocial2.Text = eachSocial.InnerText; } else { ddlSocial2.SelectedValue = "select"; }
    if (s == 3) { ddlSocial3.SelectedValue = eachSocial.Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString(); txtSocial3.Text = eachSocial.InnerText; } else { ddlSocial3.SelectedValue = "select"; }
    if (s == 4) { ddlSocial4.SelectedValue = eachSocial.Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString(); txtSocial4.Text = eachSocial.InnerText; } else { ddlSocial4.SelectedValue = "select"; }
    if (s == 5) { ddlSocial5.SelectedValue = eachSocial.Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString(); txtSocial5.Text = eachSocial.InnerText; } else { ddlSocial5.SelectedValue = "select"; }
    s = s + 1;
}
```

This is an .aspx page with C# code behind.  I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 on a Surface Pro 3 running Windows Pro 10.

Added:
I tried replacing the code above with the following code that I pulled from an old project.  I tried modifying the XML file to have child nodes of "media1," "media2," etc, on the hunch that iterating with the "foreach XMLNode" was causing problems.

```
ddlSocial1.Items.FindByValue(getPublisherData.SelectSingleNode("publisher/social/media1").Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString()).Selected = true;
ddlSocial2.Items.FindByValue(getPublisherData.SelectSingleNode("publisher/social/media2").Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Result:  I get an error that states, "Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList."

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem entirely, but it apparently has something to do with the way that I was populating the dropdown lists.

This is the code that I used to populate the dropdown lists.

```
XmlDocument getSocMedia = new XmlDocument();
getSocMedia.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/socialmedia.xml"));
XmlNodeList allAccounts = getSocMedia.SelectNodes("social/media");
foreach (XmlNode eachAccount in allAccounts)
{
    ListItem socID = new ListItem();
    socID.Value = eachAccount.Attributes["ID"].Value.ToString();
    socID.Text = eachAccount.FirstChild.InnerText.ToString();
    ddlSocial1.Items.Add(socID);
    ddlSocial2.Items.Add(socID);
    ddlSocial3.Items.Add(socID);
    ddlSocial4.Items.Add(socID);
    ddlSocial5.Items.Add(socID);
}
```

I deleted this and entered the dropdown listitems directly into the .aspx file and now it works fine.  I don't know why it works and, after many wasted hours, I don't care.  It works.  Good enough.